# How to solve Middleware authentication error?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-8

When I try to login or register or try to access a page that is restricted this error shows.
How to solve this error?

```
Declaration of App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::handle($request, Closure $next) must be compatible with Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::handle($request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
```

This is the /app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate as Middleware;
use Closure;
use Auth;
class Authenticate extends  Middleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::check()) {
            return $next($request);
        }
        return redirect()->route('user.login');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The original method's prototype (`Middleware::handle()`) is `handle($request, Closure $next, ...$guards)`, so yours must be like that too. If you don't need those `$guards`, you may not use them, but they have to be in the prototype.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate as Middleware;
use Closure;
use Auth;
class Authenticate extends  Middleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
    {
        if (Auth::check()) {
            return $next($request);
        }
        return redirect()->route('user.login');
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works.

Comment: Thankss, it works also for me